# «Когда родятся наконец новые (П)пушкины и (Л)лермонтовы»

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика

Стоит ли писать с заглавной фамилии в выражениях такого типа: «Когда родятся наконец новые (П)пушкины и (Л)лермонтовы» (имеются в виду не люди с такой фамилией, а талантливые поэты)?

Answer (score 4):

В таком предложении фамилии следует писать с заглавной буквы.

***Когда родятся, наконец, новые Пушкины и Лермонтовы.***

[**§ 11. Собственные имена лиц и клички животных**](https://old-rozental.online/orfografia.php?sid=15) (Розенталь)

> 2. Собственные имена, **ставшие именами нарицательными**, пишутся со **строчной** буквы: *альфонс, держиморда, донжуан, ловелас, ментор, меценат, ванька* (‘извозчик в дореволюционной России’), *ванька-встанька* (‘игрушка’).
>
> Если фамилия, употребленная в нарицательном значении, **не переходит в разряд существительных нарицательных**, сохраняется написание с **прописной** буквы: *Мы… твёрдо были уверены, что имеем своих **Байронов, Шекспиров, Шиллеров, Вальтер Скоттов*** (Бел.).

[**3.2.4. Индивидуальные имена, употребляемые в качестве нарицательных, но не утратившие индивидуального значения**](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091346.html#id-3%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-324%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

> пишутся с прописной буквы. Напр.: *Мы... твердо были уверены, что имеем своих **Байронов, Шекспиров, Шиллеров, Вальтер Скоттов*** (Белинский). Ср. (допустимое написание): *В окружении **кабаних**, **диких** и **феклуш** складывался свободолюбивый характер Катерины.*

Другие примеры можно посмотреть в комментарии Риммы Михайловой.

И замечание не по теме вопроса. Считаю, что слово ***наконец*** нужно выделить запятыми. В данном случае оно не имеет значения «в конечном итоге, после всего, напоследок, под конец, в результате всего», а является вводным и «выражает недовольство, нетерпение, досаду» (см. [**Грамота.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_436)).

Comment: Все хорошо, красиво, со ссылками, только дважды в ответе Вы используете одно и то же предложение. Можно вот это: _Не каждый день рождаются Гоголи и Щедрины._  (http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/139-prop) Или: _Неужто решили, что если родится какой-нибудь новый Гитлер, то он их не найдет?_ Или: _...а потому не встретит свою жену и не родится у них новый Эйнштейн._

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  Да, конечно, я осознавал, что есть повтор. Просто правило сформулировано немного по-разному, а во второй ссылке мне хотелось оставить пример написания со строчной для сравнения. В любом случае большое спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: Убедили, Александр! (Не помню, спрашивала или нет, — можно просто по имени-то?)

Comment: Римма, конечно! Отчества здесь редко можно увидеть :) А фамилию писать не стоит. Спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец  *Считаю, что слово наконец нужно выделить запятыми*  - Я бы не стал давать такую рекомендацию. Сравните с примерами отсюда http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_436. Особенно из "Метели": *…Добрая Прасковья Петровна радовалась, что дочь ее наконец нашла себе достойного жениха*. А. Пушкин, Метель.  Полагаю, в подобном контексте автор вправе трактовать "наконец" как "после всего" или  "напоследок" .

Answer (score 1):

А почему нет? Здесь же нет перехода в нарицательное (апеллятивации), вы же сами и пишете, что имеются в виду именно новые реальные Пушкины и Лермонтовы, а не какие-то условные носители таких фамилий.

*Дерзайте ныне ободренны

Раченьем вашим показать,

Что может собственных Платонов

И быстрых разумом Невтонов

Российская земля рождать.*

Ломоносов, "Ода на день восшествия..."